# In C++, how do I go about turning different lines of a txt file into multiple variables?

Tags: c++, file, text

I'm basically, trying to create a simple text adventure and each line in the save file will represent a certain string or integer.

The text file looks something like this:

```
Tyler
Boy
1a
0
```

The code looks like this:

```
 void open_file1() {
 struct file1 {
  std::string Name;
  std::string Gender;
  std::string Location;
  int Gold;

file1(std::string);
};
file1::file1(std::string"file1.txt") {
           std::ifstream Input("file1.txt".c_str());
              if (Input.is_open()) {
               std::getline(Input, this->Name);    //Reads first line into 'Name'
               std::getline(Input, this->Gender);  //Reads second line into 'Gender'
               std::getline(Input, this->Location); //Reads third line into   'Location'
    std:getline(Input, this->Gold); //Reads 4th line as 'Gold'
    cout << file1;
}
}
}
```

***file1::file1(std::string"file1.txt") {*** is where I'm getting an error... the error is this:  error: expected primary-expression before string constant

And I want each line to represent an individual variable.

So **Tyler** would be assigned to a string called name.

**Boy** would be assigned to a string called gender, etc.
All I have so far is code that writes or in my case "saves" the data into a text file that won't be modified until the player saves the game again.

Comment: I recommend using `std::vector` or array rather than trying to create variable names.  Variable names only exist during compile time and are not part of the executable (in Debug executables, they may be part of the symbol dictionary).

Comment: Try to add more content about what you want to do exactly and add some code you already begin to write ?

Comment: You should explain what exactly is preventing you from doing this.

Comment: I don't know how -_-

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could benefit from a container of structures.

Let's assume:

```
struct Player
{
  std::string name;
  std::string gender;
  // other data
};
```

You could implement a `std::vector<Player>` to hold instances (or in your terms *variables*) of Players.  This is the usual technique among programmers.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Matthews says, you're better off wrapping all your variables up in a nice `struct` bundle:

```
struct Player 
{
    std::string Name;
    std::string Gender;
    std::string Data;
    int OtherData;
};
```

As for 'loading' from a file, you could easily create a constructor to load the data into the `Player` object:

```
#include <fstream> //So we can use std::ifstream

struct Player 
{
    std::string Name;
    std::string Gender;
    std::string Data;
    int OtherData;

    Player(std::string); //Our custom constructor
};

Player::Player(std::string fileName) {
    std::ifstream Input(fileName.c_str());
    if (Input.is_open()) {
        std::getline(Input, this->Name);    //Reads first line into 'Name'
        std::getline(Input, this->Gender);  //Reads second line into 'Gender'
        //etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can get you some directions but they are far away from completed.
You can work more on error handling, output formatting, class design etc..

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using std::string;


// Player.h
class Player
{

public:
    // Constructors
    Player(string inName, string inGender, string inLocation, size_t inGold)
        : mName {inName}, mGender {inGender}
        , mLocation {inLocation}, mGold {inGold} {}
    // Default constructor
    Player()=default;
    // Copy constructor
    Player(const Player& player)
        : mName {player.mName}, mGender {player.mGender}
        , mLocation {player.mLocation}, mGold {player.mGold}  {}

   // This constructor is for demo only, move implementation to Player.cpp
   Player(const string& filename)
    {
        // Open the file and check for errors.
        ifstream inFile {filename.c_str()};
        if (!inFile) {
            throw invalid_argument("Unable to open file"); }
        // Read the names one at a time.
        for (Player player; inFile >> player; ) {
            // You can check that player is valid
            mName = player.mName;
            mGender = player.mGender;
            mLocation = player.mLocation;
            mGold = player.mGold;
        }

        inFile.close();
    }


private:
    string mName;
    string mGender;
    string mLocation;
    size_t mGold;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Player& player);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Player& player);
};

inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Player& player)
{
    return in >> player.mName     >> player.mGender
              >> player.mLocation >> player.mGold;
}

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Player& player)
{
    return out << std::setw(10) << player.mName << ' '
    << std::setw(10) << player.mGender  << ' '
    << std::setw(10) << player.mLocation << ' '
    << std::setw(10) << player.mGold << '\n';
}





// Test app

int main()
{

    Player player1 {"player1.txt"};
    cout << "Player 1: " << player1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```